Error duplicate key value violates unique constraint 'revinfo_pkey' during audit table insertion after Hibernate Envers 6.4.4.Final upgrade
After upgrading Java from 11 to 21 and Hibernate Envers to 6.4.4.Final, I encountered the following error while saving data into the audit table:

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "revinfo_pkey"

I am using @Audited and @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class) to create audit tables. I already have multiple audit tables and a revinfo table with existing entries. The error occurs because the insert process is not appending to the end of the revinfo table, but instead starting from the beginning, causing intermittent duplicate key violations. Ideally, it should start inserting after the last entry.
How can I resolve this issue?
I attempted further upgrades to resolve this issue, but the problem persists. I prefer not to clean all the audit tables as they contain rev columns that are foreign keys referencing the revinfo table.
My goal is to restore the previous behavior, where new entries in the revinfo table follow the last existing entry without causing key duplication.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Same case. I found solution:
add this Property hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy=legacy
Here is Article for this solution:
HIbernate 6 migration.

Implicit Identifier Sequence and Table Name The way in which Hibernate
determines implicit names for sequences and tables associated with
identifier generation has changed in 6.0 which may affect migrating
applications.
As of 6.0, Hibernate by default creates a sequence per entity
hierarchy instead of a single sequence hibernate_sequence.
Due to this change, users that previously used
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.AUTO) or simply
@GeneratedValue (since AUTO is the default), need to ensure that the
database now contains sequences for every entity, named _seq. For an entity Person, a sequence person_seq is expected to
exist. It’s best to run hbm2ddl (e.g. by temporarily setting
hbm2ddl.auto=create) to obtain a list of DDL statements for the
sequences.
Users that use a import.sql file to import test or static data during
application boot or for tests have to make sure the new sequences
match expectations of Hibernate. If a import.sql file contains
references to the hibernate_sequence, these have to be replaced with
_seq. Also note that the default allocation size changed
for such implicit sequences.
To help with backwards compatibility, or to apply any general naming
strategy, 6.0 introduces the
org.hibernate.id.enhanced.ImplicitDatabaseObjectNamingStrategy
contract which can be specified using the
hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy setting. See discussion at
link:https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#ID_DB_STRUCTURE_NAMING_STRATEGY
For backwards compatibility, use either
hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy=single or
hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy=legacy depending on needs

